# android set inputtext value

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, textinput

I'm a young computer scientist and I'm learning android development.

I tried since this morning to pass value between 2 `inputtext` on the same layout.
When the user edit one `inputtext`, I would like to paste the new value to one other `inputtext`.

This is my code :

```
private void syncInput() { 
     ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstInput)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {              
            EditText EditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstInput);
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.SecondInput)).setText(EditTextATK.EditText1().toString());

        }        
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }        
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }        
    });

}
```

After the launch of my application, when I edit my firstInput I have this **error** :

```
06-22 14:08:25.196: E/AndroidRuntime(519): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 14:08:25.196: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at com.d3ckard.toolbox.activity.MyActivity$3.afterTextChanged(MyActivity.java:71)
06-22 14:08:25.196: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6145)
06-22 14:08:25.196: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:6328)
06-22 14:08:25.196: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextHasChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:897)
06-22 14:08:25.196: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:353)
06-22 14:08:25.196: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
06-22 14:08:25.196: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
06-22 14:08:25.196: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
06-22 14:08:25.196: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
06-22 14:08:25.196: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:117)
```

---

The line number 71 is this one :

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.SecondInput)).setText(EditTextATK.EditText1().toString());
```

Comment: ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.SecondInput)).setText(EditTextATK.EditText1().toString()); - I would guess thats the problem. I am not sure what you are trying to do there but you should change it

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.SecondInput)).setText(EditTextATK.EditText1().toString());
```

to

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.SecondInput)).setText(EditText1().getText().toString());
```

Comment: Oh good I found why the nullPointerException is.
It's a shame, but it's because the SecondInput has no data.
When i fill secondInput with data, and then when i type in FirstInput, the sync goes well.
How can i prevent this nullpointerException so ?
Thank you

Comment: But that should not be the case. Why there is a need of data in 2nd EditText while you are going to fill it from 1st EditText?

Comment: You're right, but do u have any clue to prevent this exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
private void syncInput() { 
             EditText EditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstInput);
             EditText EditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SecondInput);
             EditText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {              

                    EditText2.setText(EditText1.gettext().toString());

                }        
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }        
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }        
            });

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for all your replies, but it still don't work.
Here is my code :
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {     
     EditText EditTextATK = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FirstInput);
     Log.v(TAG, "value input ATK : " + EditTextATK.getText().toString());
     EditText EditTextDEF = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SecondInput);
     EditTextDEF.setText(EditTextATK.getText().toString());   
      }

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code is missing `getText()`.  It shoudl be:

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.SecondInput)).setText(EditTextATK.EditText1().getText().toString());
```